# Dynamic Linq to SQL - Where Not Like

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I apologize if this has been covered already but I was unable to find a solution to fit my code. I am new to Linq and still a beginner in SQL. I am working in C# and ASP.Net.

I setup a WhereLike extension to IQueryable so that I can dynamically choose the column and data to query. (The database has a lot of columns so it would be a nightmare to strongly type every one.) This WhereLike extension works great but I need to know how to change it to 'NOT Like'.

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string pattern)
{
    if (null == source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");
    //When using variables, system adds -> "'5555'"
    if (pattern.StartsWith("'") && pattern.EndsWith("'"))
    { pattern = pattern.Substring(1, pattern.Length - 2); }

    MethodInfo refmethod = typeof(SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
    var value = Expression.Constant(pattern);
    var body = Expression.Call(null, refmethod, prop, value);
    var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    return source.Where(fn);
}
```

Grant it that the application was working great before it was decided to move to Linq. This is the code I have which is using the extension above:

```
// linq, column, data, type (0=not, 1=like)
protected IQueryable<FIM> setupLINQQueryFIM(IQueryable<FIM> linq, string a, string b, int c = 1)
{
    if (c == 0)
    {
        linq = linq.WhereNotLike(a, b);
    }
    else if (c == 1)
    {
        linq = linq.WhereLike(a, b);
    }
    return linq;
}
```

I call this function as many times as needed, then loop through a foreach statement with the IQueryable to save everything to a DataTable. As I've mentioned, it works great except I can not get a WhereNotLike working at all.
Please let me know if it is possible or if any more information is needed.

Update: Per comments below; I found that I could achieve 'Not Like' by wrapping the `Expression.Call` with `Expression.Not`. Works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: I guess not like is just what it says. To make it in linq just wrap the "body" expression of your WhereLike into Expression.Not - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299047.aspx

Comment: @Ondra - Looks like that worked! It failed the first time I tried due to a tired mistake.
`var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(body), param);`
Thanks for your help. MUCH appreciated.

Comment: @CloudD901 Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm glad you found your answer! To make it clear for other users who have the same problem, please add the solution as an Answer below.

Comment: I added an answer with Expression.Not. I´l happy if you mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To negate your condition, just wrap it into Expression.Not - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299047.aspx

```
...   
var body = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(null, refmethod, prop, value));
var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
...
```